# How to Add the bulk recipient file to the envelope?

Tags: docusignapi

I tried bulk send through REST API using this [link](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/using-bulk-send-in-rest.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____40), but could not upload bulk recipient file. Can you please suggest how can we upload CSV file to a 'Draft Envelope/Template'.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of such API call:

```
PUT https://{server}/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/1/bulk_recipients

X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"[username]","Password":"[password]","IntegratorKey":"[integratorKey]"}
Content-Type: text/csv

Name,Email,Note,AccessCode,Identification,PhoneNumber,address1
David Jones,david.jones@yahoo.com,Here is the document we discussed.,,SMS,1200300400,123 Main St
Kevin Smith,kevinmith@yahoo.com,,2243,,,697 My Way
Elisabeth Bozick,elisabeth.bozick@yahoo.com,,,phone,usersupplied,827 1st Ave
```